# Custom Cursor - change scale while moving fast

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created a custom cursor and I want to change its scale dynamically on fast movements.
It's a cursor like this one: [Cuberto.com](https://cuberto.com/)

My cursor: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-moore-kqigf?file=/src/components/CustomCursor.vue)

When the cursor moves quickly to the right or left, scaleX should grow and get smaller again.
When the cursor moves up or down, scaleY should grow and so on...

**Edit: New challenge - Get rotation in**

Thanks to Terry, who achieved this goal!
But now we have a new challenge.
If we move the cursor diagonally, the cursor still has to rotate to get a perfect result.

[Terry's CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-easley-7odl4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I would divide the velocity by '2'. If we now move the cursor diagonally, we can see that rotation is missing to achieve the desired effect.

Does anyone have an idea?

```js
const scaleX = 1 + velocityX / 2;
const scaleY = 1 + velocityY / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create this effect, here are some steps to achieve that, starting from the end:

1. You will want to use [`scaleX()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX()) and [`scaleY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleY()) in CSS transforms
2. You will therefore need to somehow get the velocity of the cursor movement in the x and y axis
3. To get the velocity you will need the following information:

   - The current position of the cursor (easily accessed via the `MouseEvent` object)
   - The previous position of the cursor (you will need to cache this)
   - The time elapsed between the previous mouse event and current mouse event

With this strategy in mind, here is how it could be done:

### Step 1: Allow your `data` object to cache the previous XY coordinates *and* timestamp

This can be done by simply updating the `data` object:

```
data() {
  return {
    hideCursor: false,
    prevX: 0,
    prevY: 0,
    prevTimeStamp: 0,
  };
},
```

### Step 2: Ensure that you cache these values in your `mousemove` callback:

We need to store these values at the very end of the `mousemove` callback, and place the rest of our logic before that (we will get to that later).

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  // SOME LOGIC HERE

  // Update cached values
  this.prevX = e.pageX;
  this.prevY = e.pageY;
  this.prevTimeStamp = e.timeStamp;
});
```

### Step 3: Calculate velocity by comparing current and previous value

To calculate velocity in the X and Y axes, you need to calculate the absolute difference between previous and current X/Y values, and divide them by the time elapsed:

```
const deltaX = Math.abs(e.pageX - this.prevX);
const deltaY = Math.abs(e.pageY - this.prevY);
const deltaTime = e.timeStamp - this.prevTimeStamp;
const velocityX = deltaX / deltaTime;
const velocityY = deltaY / deltaTime;
```

### Step 4: Determine how to translate velocities into CSS scale transform

**This is completely arbitrarily determined and it's up to you**. For me, dividing the calculated velocity by 10 gives an effect that I find not too jarring/abrupt and still perceptible to the user. This value might need to be changed based on the absolute pixel size of the cursor.

```
const scaleX = 1 + velocityX / 10;
const scaleY = 1 + velocityY / 10;

cursor.style.top = `${e.pageY}px`;
cursor.style.left = `${e.pageX}px`;
cursor.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) scaleX(${scaleX}) scaleY(${scaleY})`;
```

### (Optional) Step 5: Ensure that you handle `mouseout` event on the viewport

This is so that the cursor is not stuck in a strange state when mouse leaves the viewport:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  cursor.style.transform = 'none';
});
```

---

See an updated example based on your CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit vigorous-easley-7odl4]